# Set an property to object after query.exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using node express. I am trying to populate a field which is populated from another field. But I was having problem so I tried to get the value from another query and then set it to the object I was sending.

```
api.get('/:id', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    let query = MobileTranscation.findById(req.params.id)
        .populate('sender')
        .populate('created_by');

    query.exec((err, datas) => {
        if(datas.sender && datas.sender.parent) {
            User.findById(datas.sender.parent, (err, user) => {
                datas['parentName'] = user.username;

                console.log(datas);
                res.json(datas);
            });
        } else {
            res.json(datas);
        }
    });
});
```

Here, I want to get username from MobileTranscation.sender in which sender has a parent property which has the username property. I was trying to populate sender and then take the parent id and search User with that and get the username. Problem I am facing is that if I log datas.parentName I can see I got the username, but when I am sending datas, there is no parentName property. What I am doing wrong here?

And is it possible to populate a property and then populate one of that populated property?

Comment: Whenever you do findById mongoose actually sends some kind of immutable object in return. So you cannot add an extra key to the object. You actually can use the .lean function. Like `query.lean().exec((err, data) => { /** Function body* */ })`. Now you can add extra keys you want.

Comment: That does work mate.. thanks

Comment: You can add that as an answer. Will mark as right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you do findById mongoose actually sends some kind of immutable object in return. So you cannot add an extra key to the object. You actually can use the .lean function. Like `query.lean().exec((err, data) => { /** Function body* */ })`. Now you can add extra keys you want.